# Graph traversal with Networkx (Python)

Tags: python, networkx

I'm playing a bit with Networkx to manage a graph of dependencies.
Let's say I have this Graph which each letter represent a server

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge("A","B")
>>> G.add_edge("A","H")
>>> G.add_edge("H","C")
>>> G.add_edge("B","C")
>>> G.add_edge("B","D")

           A
         /   \
       H       B
     /        /  \
   C         C     D
```

So here we can see that before starting A we need to start H and B and to start H we need to start C and then to start B wee need to start C and D

By fiddling a bit with Networkx I found that I can get that by doing a dfs traversal

```
print nx.dfs_successors(G,"A")
{A:[H,B], H:[C], B:[D] }
```

But I have a problem with that method. As you can see when there is two same letter in the tree, Networkx only chose to put one of them in the final structure (which is correct) But I need to have the complete structure
How can I force Networkx to add in the structure B:[D,C] ??

I want to precise that by doing

```
>>> nx.dfs_successors(G,"B")
{'B': ['C', 'D']}
```

So everything is "Internally" correct, it's just the dfs_successors that displays it not in the way I wish.

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taking your code, your graph doesn't come out as you'd expect. If you do:

```
import pylab as p
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("A","B")
G.add_edge("A","H")
G.add_edge("H","C")
G.add_edge("B","C")
G.add_edge("B","D")

nx.draw(G)
p.show()
```

you will see your graph as:
[image: Graph]

This is due to the logic of `G.add_edge("A", "B")`:

1. If `G` has no node of id "A", add it.
2. If `G` has no node of id "B", add it.
3. Connect "A" to "B" with a new edge.

Thus, you only create five nodes, not six as in your picture.

**Edit**
Networkx can take any hashable as value for a node, and in the graph it uses str(node) to label each circle. So we can simply define our own Node class (which you maybe want to call Server?) and give it the desired behavior.

```
import pylab as p
import networkx as nx


class Node(object):
    nodes = []

    def __init__(self, label):
        self._label = label

    def __str__(self):
        return self._label

nodes = [Node(l) for l in ["A","B","C","C","D","H"]]
edges = [(0,1),(0,5),(5,2),(1,3),(1,4)]

G = nx.Graph()
for i,j in edges:
    G.add_edge(nodes[i], nodes[j])

nx.draw(G)
p.show()
```

gives us
[image: New graph]
and so what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for drawing the graph. This is what I "thought" Networkx was doing in my back. Thus my question would be: How with Networkx create a tree like in my example?
tipically what would ideal for me is when i create the G.add_edge("B","C") a new Node "C" is create insead of reusing the on connected to H.

Comment: Then you would need to call the new node something else.  C1 and C2, perhaps.  NetworkX doesn't allow multiple nodes with the same label, to my knowledge.

Comment: But I need the node to have the same. like i said in the main thread. my node are servername, I can't change the names otherwise I don't know which one is which...
But really the Graph that Thorsten Kranz is not "Wrong" it is correct, B depends of "C AND D". it is just that the algorithm "dfs_successors()" output that B only depends on D and THAT is wrong
If my tree is not possible with Networkx, would that be possible with an other lib? thanks

Comment: Added second example, hope this fits your needs.

Comment: can the edges be labeled as well?

Answer (score 10):

I think what you are looking for is a topological sort https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html

This only works if you have a DAG (directed acyclic graph).
If so you can draw the tree you want too - like this:

```
import uuid
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge("A","B")
G.add_edge("A","H")
G.add_edge("H","C")
G.add_edge("B","C")
G.add_edge("B","D")

order =  nx.topological_sort(G)
print "topological sort"
print order

# build tree
start = order[0]
nodes = [order[0]] # start with first node in topological order
labels = {}
print "edges"
tree = nx.Graph()
while nodes:
    source = nodes.pop()
    labels[source] = source
    for target in G.neighbors(source):
        if target in tree:
            t = uuid.uuid1() # new unique id
        else:
            t = target
        labels[t] = target
        tree.add_edge(source,t)
        print source,target,source,t
        nodes.append(target)

nx.draw(tree,labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

The drawing uses a label mapping to map the ids of the node to the original labels.

[image]

Comment: The provided link is broken