# Networkx graph remove redundant paths to compute level order

Tags: networkx

Consider the following graph structure from the [data set](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/512955/48271586/) for networkx digraph. When the above data set is converted into a tree:

[image]

A topological sort gives the following output in level order (more or less and which is what I am looking for), but does NOT provide information about **each levels** every node corresponds to. ex: n0:Level-0, n2:Level-1 and n3:Level-1 so on.

```
print(nx.topological_sort(G))
['n2', 'n1', 'n0', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9', 'n24', 'n27', 'n21', 'n23', 'n50', 'n15', 'n14', 'n16', 'n17', 'n25', 'n18', 'n19', 'n42', 'n28', 'n38', 'n30', 'n31', 'n32', 'n39', 'n33', 'n34', 'n35', 'n36', 'n37', 'n49', 'n41', 'n40', 'n43', 'n44', 'n29', 'n22', 'n20', 'n26', 'n45', 'n48', 'n46', 'n47', 'n51', 'n54', 'n52', 'n53', 'n11', 'n10', 'n13', 'n12', 'n55']
```

Therefore, I further processed the data set to with `nextworkx.single_source_shortest_path_length()` and sort the order based on the level. Since there are several edges in the di-graph the single source shortest path output is not very accurate.

```
from operator import itemgetter
nd = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,'n0')
sorted(nd.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
[('n0', 0),
 ('n12', 1),
 ('n13', 1),
 ...
 ('n4', 1),
 ('n5', 1),
 ('n6', 1),
 ('n7', 1)]
```

To fix this I am trying to figure out a solution based on the following approaches:
1. By removing redundant paths and compute the level order using `single_source_shortest_path()`. To achieve this, I may have to remove the redundant paths such that every node has only one path until the root (n0), through it parent. Redundant path's all the paths except for a path which are visiting nearby nodes (parent) on the way to root node (n0). Therefore, a node can have only one path to the root (not necessarily the shortest path).

ex: If the node (n221) is have an edge to the parent (n22) and another edge the a grand parent (n or n2), remove all edge{s} to the grandparent (remove edge n221 ---> n), if the parent (n22) is having an edge (n22 ---> n) to the grandparent.

2. I can get the topological sort output. With the output can I reconstruct a simpler tree using `nx.topological_sort(G)` and `nx.bfs_successors(G, 'n0')` similar to what is acheived in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259233/graph-traversal-with-networkx-python)

Ultimately want to get the below result to iterate each level starting from n0 as root:

```
Levels: nodes   
1: n0
2: n3, n21
3: n4
4: n5
6: n7, n15 ...
7: ...
```

What am I missing here to achieve the correct result, and how can I get my expected behavior ?

I am dealing with very large data set with ~1.5K nodes, therefore have taken a simple example here instead of presenting the complete data set.

Comment: What level would you consider `n1` and `n2`?  They are either disconnected or new roots.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to remove any edges from a leaf node (defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946253/find-end-nodes-leaf-nodes-in-radial-tree-networkx-graph)) to the root node when the leaf has both:

1. an edge to the root node
2. an alternate path to the root

The graph `G` above is a little messy and doesn't exactly match up with your 'pictorial' depiction.  (For example, n511 isn't shown)

```py
import matplotlib as plt
import networkx as nx

pos=nx.drawing.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

If I understand correctly, this solution could help.  It iterates through the leaves and checks if the leaf has >1 path to the root node.  The nested if condition checks for a direct edge between `leaf` and the root node `'n'`

```py
removed = []
for leaf in (x for x in G.nodes_iter() if G.out_degree(x)==0 and G.in_degree(x)>=1):
    if sum(1 for _ in nx.all_simple_paths(G, 'n', leaf)) >1: # equivalent to len(generator)
            if G.has_edge('n',leaf):
                removed.append(('n', leaf)) # shows edges removed
                G.remove_edge('n', leaf)

print(removed)
[('n', 'n221'), ('n', 'n51'), ('n', 'n131')]
```

It cleans up the graph, this may break if node `'n'` is not truly the root.

```py
pos=nx.drawing.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(G, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's my last attempt, probably should've left this for someone more knowledgeable to answer.  Try iterating the nodes and extract the longest path from root to node.  There has to be a better way to perform this operation, maybe someone can recommend.

*Assume `G` is created from the code in the link you provided in the comments.*

```py
G1 = nx.DiGraph()
for n in nodes:
    if n == 'n0': # skip n0
        continue
    if not nx.has_path(G, 'n0', n): #n1 and n2 are disconnected from n0
        lpath= max(list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, n, 'n55')), key=len)
        G1.add_path(lpath)
        continue
    lpath= max(list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, 'n0', n)), key=len)
    G1.add_path(lpath)

#levels
sorted(nx.shortest_path_length(G1, 'n0').items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) # omits n1, n2

[('n0', 0),
 ('n21', 1),
 ('n3', 1),
 ('n4', 2),
 ('n5', 3),
 ('n15', 4),
 ('n24', 4),
 ('n6', 4),
 ('n7', 4),
 ('n8', 5),
 ('n12', 6),
 (...


plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
pos=nx.drawing.nx_pydot.pydot_layout(G1, prog='dot')
nx.draw(G1, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks your inputs are very useful! I need to try this on my data set, before updating. While I am trying to plot a large number of nodes and edges. Is there a way I could increase the size of the edges and node labels, since this png shows as a cluster of red and black dots ?

Comment: The code sample provided above does not work with my data set / tree in question. Here is the link to the list of edges in the tree. https://paste.fedoraproject.org/512955/48271586/ Could you please confirm what I am missing here ?

Comment: Note: 'n0' is the root node in the above data set

Comment: Thanks for posting the data, I'll be able to take a look tomorrow. :)

Comment: From the data set provided the edges to an di-graph and 'n0' is the root. The tree is not formed based on the node names. The objective is to process the nodes in level order (or BFS). Sol1: Use networkx topological sort which gives me the desired results ordered a single list but not level ordered. Sol2: Remove redundant paths from leaf to root (n0), and then get sorted output networkx single_source_shortest_path_length(G,'n0'), which give where each node is associated in level. But getting the single source shortest path without the rem the some paths does not give the desired results.

Comment: This (http://imgur.com/a/9x2gI) gives a more accurate pic representation of the data set provided earlier. The earlier approach to removed the redundant path to the root node, is better option, but unfortunately this does not work for the data set! What could be missing ?

Comment: I am now able to convert the earlier png into a more readable tree from dot format: http://imgur.com/a/ZnQex

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I will run some tests to confirm! But overall the approach looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but I think what you want is for there to be only one path from the root to any node in the graph.

If that is your requirement, the only way to fulfill it is with a tree. If I understood correctly, you also want all the remaining paths to be the shortest one to the root, in which case the tree you're looking for is exactly the BFS tree.

You can get it in NetworkX like this:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('n', 'n1'), ('n', 'n2'), ('n', 'n3'), ('n', 'n4'), ('n', 'n5')])
G.add_edges_from([('n4', 'n41'), ('n1', 'n11'), ('n1', 'n12'), ('n1', 'n13'), ('n5', 'n51'), ('n12', 'n131')])
G.add_edges_from([('n2', 'n21'), ('n2', 'n22'), ('n', 'n221'), ('n', 'n51')])
G.add_edges_from([('n13', 'n131'), ('n22', 'n221'), ('n', 'n131'), ('n', 'n221'), ('n', 'n511')])

G = nx.bfs_tree(G, 'n')

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Which produces something like this:

[image: BFS Tree of the given graph]

Comment: In my case, I wanted to keep the longest path instead, so I used: `nx.dfs_tree(G, 'n')`.